# Extra allowances not being added to gross salary

Tags: java

I'm doing a project, and in this 100 employees names and basic salaries need to be accepted. With these, we need to calculate dearness and something else allowances. These need to be added to the gross salary and displayed. However, the gross salary keeps on showing as the value it was initialized as, without adding on SA and DA.

I've tried adding brackets in the conditions. That's all that comes to mind! (I'm a very beginner-level school student)

```
    //To input percentage and print division.
    import java.util.*;
     class prog24
   {
       public static void main()
         {
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Input name."); 
           System.out.println("Input your basic salary.");
           double da = 1;
           double sa = 1;
           double gs = 0;
           for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
          `

           String name = input.next();
          int basic = input.nextInt();





    if(basic<=10000)
    {
       da = (10/100)*basic;
       sa = (5/100) * basic;
    }
    else if(basic<=20000 && basic>10000)
    {
       da = (12/100)*basic;
       sa = (8/100) * basic;
    }
    else if(basic<=30000 && basic>20000)
    {
       da = (15/100) *basic;
       sa = (10/100) * basic;
    }
    else
    {
       da = (20/100) *basic;
       sa = (12/100) * basic;
     }
      gs = basic + da + sa;
      System.out.println("Gross salary = "+gs);
      gs = 1;
      da = 1;
      sa = 1;
      basic = 1;
      }}}
```

For input = 15000,
expected: 17250.0
actual: 15000.0

Comment: Two integer operation will result in int. You need to cast it to double/float to get the proper result. For example: (10/100) will result in 0 as it is

Comment: OMGOMOGMG this worked. Thank you so so much, Mr. Master Programmer! I was worried that I would not be able to submit my project tomorrow! You are a lifesaver. I did not expect such a quick response. Is there any way I can repay you?

Comment: Since this has helped you, to keep it as a better record, I left the comment as an answer below. I suggest you accept it as an answer. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two integer operation will result in int. You need to cast it to double/float to get the proper result. For example: (10/100) will result in 0 as it is.

Comment: You're the best! This worked perfectly. Loving the site already!